# File in Internet Explorer 11 opened from source URL instead of tempory folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, ms-office, internet-explorer-11

I would like you to help me to understand this situation. From a web application (ASP.NET MVC), I generate files in docx and xlsx. In Internet Explorer (V11) it show a box asking if user want to "Open", "Save" or "Save as" this file. When user select "Open", it open the file in Microsoft Word (or Excel), but the file is not in Internet Explorer's temporary file folder. File point toward the web application URL. This cause an issue when user "Enable Editing" on this opened docx or xlsx file. The "Enable Editing" action change the content of the file for the login page of the web application, which is wrong.

The issue doesn't happend in Chrome or Firefox, nor if user "Save" or "Save as" files. Too, it doesn't happend on all PCs.

Until now I did: compare IE advance setting with a working PC, compare IE security setting with a working PC, reset IE settings and opened a docx file from GMail (the issue didn't happen)

I use Microsoft office 2013

Thanks for your advices

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

In my code I didn't have the Response header "content-disposition" when generating files.

Comment: did @Raphael you try with Content-disposition=inline ? . I have same problem

Comment: I didn't tries "Content-disposition=inline". I use Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", ReporExportFileName); and ReporExportFileName = "attachment; filename=MyFile.xlsx"